# GitLab yaml file with teams webhook to send notifications

Tags: gitlab-ci, microsoft-teams, webhooks

I am trying to send notifications through the GitLab yaml file to the teams, but getting the error like `curl: (3) <url> malformed` when I use the curl command.

```
curl: (3) <url> malformed
100   127    0     0  100   127      0   7536 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7536
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mywebhook4; Unknown error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mmse2dr-fckc-5a83-9rfa-8hfbffb4faeab; Unknown error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: IncomingWebhook; Unknown error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 58ea0bfgnnvfkn80748c0bd36423b294e9990; Unknown error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ad7f2ba2-b055-45ft-a51f-64160acd13f3; Unknown error
```

I am sending the payload as follows

```
curl -X POST -d '{ "@type": "MessageCard", "themeColor": "#00FF00", "text": "'"testing the webhook"'"}' $TeamsWebhookUrl
 expected result should be 1 and we should get notification in teams as "testing the webhook"
```

Comment: Is the variable `$TeamsWebhookUrl` set properly?

Comment: yes, $TeamsWebhookUrl set properly

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with the below command -

```
curl -X POST -d "{ '@type': 'MessageCard', 'themeColor': '#00FF00', 'text': 'testing the webhook'}" $TeamsWebhookUrl
```

It sends card like below - [image]

Comment: sure, but when I test my Payload in my local system i am getting the notification to the channel, but when i run the pipeline I'm getting this issue.

Comment: Could you please let us know how you are doing this and also please share if you are facing same 'curl: (3) <url> malformed' issue as mentioned in the question?